# Android Studio : How to set a Drawable to a buttonTextColor Programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-button, android-text-color

How can I set a drawable for button text color programmatically as in XML ?

I am creating a servel buttons and I want to change their text color when pressed.

The method `btn.setTextColor()` has an integer as entry which represents a color value so when I put a drawable in there it is considered as color.

```
private void showDialog(List list) {
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogfor_each_activity, null);
    LinearLayout ll = mView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    ll.setWeightSum((float)list.size());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogfor_each_activity);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = (int) (displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.90);
    int height = (int) (displaymetrics.heightPixels * 0.50);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(list.get(i).toString());
        btn.setTag(list.get(i).toString());
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.strockbtn_white_to_roundbtn_white);
        btn.setTextColor(R.drawable.text_blue_to_white);
        btn.setTextSize(15);
        btn.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        btn.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        params.setMargins(150, 6, 150, 6);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll.addView(btn);
        buttons.add(btn);
    }
    dialog.setContentView(mView);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I want the buttonTextColor to be set to `R.drawable.text_blue_to_white` like in XML.

> EDIT : This is not a duplicate question I already done what I want in a another way.

I need the equivalent java code for (if it is possible):

```
android:textColor="@drawable/text_blue_to_white"
```

Comment: btn.setTextColor wants a color or a selector, not a drawable.

Comment: what color do you want it to set to?

Comment: @user1506104 it is not a duplicate i saw a lot of similar questions but none of them is like mine , i dont want to set a color for my buttonTextColor i want to set a Drawable to it programmatically

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti that's what i am looking for , how to set a Drawable for buttonTextColor like we do in XML

Comment: i see. so what does text_blue_to_white do? changes the text color on button click?

Comment: @user1506104 yes it does and the button is being created in The function above

Comment: i see. pls check my answer.

Comment: @user1506104 i did and it worked , thank you my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a color resource in `res/color/blue_to_white`:

```
<selector>
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <item android:color="#0000ff"/>
</selector>
```

Then do:

```
btn.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.blue_to_white));
```

EDIT: Upon revisiting https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int), `getColorStateList(int)` is deprecated in API 23. If your target is >= API 23, simply:

```
btn.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.blue_to_white, getTheme()));
```

Comment: that's it thnk's a lot my friend

Answer (score 1):

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourcolor);
```

or

```
button.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.yourcolorColor));
```

and create a color ressource for each state of your desired Color

Comment: your answer is very wierd i think it is not supposed for this question because i dont have textView i am creating a button dynamically and i want to change that button text when pressed

Comment: Instead of textview put button .it's that simple.

Comment: I dont want to set a color a want to set a Drawable for my buttonTextColor : ```R.drawable.text_blue_to_white